# How to view machine code?

Tags: assembly, att

I've written a program in assembly (at&t syntax) and I want to see how the machine code looks. This is how I get executable code:

```
as -g -o p1.o p1.s --32 -gstabs
ld -o p1 p1.o -m elf_i386
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are on a Linux or BSD platform (based on the fact that you're using `as`), you might want to try `objdump`.

`objdump -d <binary file>` will disassemble the object file, showing you machine code hex bytes on the left and the disassembled matching assembly mnemonics on the right.  Here's an example:

```
$ objdump -d factorial

factorial:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .init:

00000000004003f0 :
  4003f0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4003f4:   e8 73 00 00 00          callq  40046c
  ..
Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000400408 :
  400408:   ff 35 e2 0b 20 00       pushq  0x200be2(%rip)        # 600ff0
  40040e:   ff 25 e4 0b 20 00       jmpq   *0x200be4(%rip)        # 600ff8
  400414:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

`objdump` is a part of the `binutils` package on Linux platforms.

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thank you!